# Netlogo gis (road network): Copying distance (feature) from gis to road-links in netlogo

Tags: netlogo

I have a netlogo gis model consisting of a road network. The .shp file  has an attribute length which measures the distance of the roads. The polyline making up the roads in the .shp file are exploded, so that distance between each vertex can be found. 
Instead of using netlogo to calculate the distance ( I presume it uses the coordinates to calculate distance between vertices), which will result the distance values in netlogo units. I am wondering if its possible to copy the length attribute from the gis file to the corresponding links? This will give the actual distances in the roads

Any ideas how to do this?

Thanks

In the netlogo model I have looped over each of the feature list, copied the "distance" from the .shp file. Then looped over the vertices, created the vertices (nodes).Then formed a linked between previous and current vertex (node).
i.e node/vertex list: vertex 137 vertex 141 vertex 150 vertex 205 ....
i.e link list: link 137 141 (end1: vertex 137  end2: vertex 141) , link 150 205 (end1: vertex 150 end2: vertex 205) ...

The idea is to have some variable like distance-in-meters as a links-owns variable. This variable will store the distance value of the link.

```
breed [vertices vertex]
links-own [distance_in_meters]



foreach gis:feature-lists-of roads[
i ->
set dist_meters gis:property-value i "LENGTH"
  foreach gis:vertex-list-of i[
  j ->
  let first-node nobody
  let previous-node nobody
    foreach j[
    k ->
    let location gis:location-of k
    if not empty? location[
    ifelse any? vertices with [xcor = item 0 location and ycor = item 1 
    location]
    []
    [
    create-vertices 1[
      set xcor item 0 location
      set ycor item 1 location
      set shape "circle"
      set size 0.2
    ]
    ]

  let node-here (vertices with [xcor = item 0 location and ycor = item 1 
  location]
  if-else previous-node-point = nobody
  [set first-node node-here]
  [let who-node 0
   let who-prev 0
   as node-here
   [create-link-with previous-node
   set who-node who]
   ask previous-node-point [set who-prev who]
   ]
  set previous-node one-of nodes-here
]]]]
```

Comment: Is the distance attribute you're interested in the total distance for the road or the distance between vertices?

Comment: Hi luke. I am interested in the distance between the vertices. Since what I am trying to achieve from my model  is to see during one tick, how much distance my agent has moved. My agent will move a couple of vertices until it reaches another agent and at that point, I was thinking calculating the total distance he has traveled by summing distance between the vertices which will be stored in a list